# question on rss feed application

Tags: java, xml, rss

i just want to create a simple application that will allow a user to input a url to a rss feed and display the contents to a user.

what would be a good java library to enable me to read rss feeds?

cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rome http://rome.dev.java.net/ - is the popular java library for parsing RSS feeds

Answer (score 1):

**Informa** is a very good java library for RSS feeds and can be found on **sourceforge.net**.The best part of this it implements Observer design pattern , hence keep checking if any new items are found on the RSS URL. Also you can set a frequency to crawl a number of URLs.